# Cassandra secondary index get_indexed_slices timing out

Tags: indexing, cassandra

I am using Cassandra 0.8 with 2 secondary indexes for columns like "DeviceID" and "DayOfYear". I have these two indexes in order to retrieve data for a device within a range of dates. Whenever I get a date filter, I convert this into DayOfYear and search using indexed slices using .net Thrift API. Currently I cannot upgrade the DB as well.

My problem is I usually do not have any issues retrieving rows using the get_indexed_slices query for the current date (using current day of year). But whenever I query for yesterday's day of year (which is one of the indexed column), I get a time out for the first time I make the query. And most of the times, it returns when I query the second time and 100% during the third time.

Both these columns are created as double data type in the column family and I generally get 1 record per minute. I have 3 nodes in the cluster and the nodetool reports suggest that the nodes are up and running, though the load distribution report from nodetool looks like this.

Starting NodeTool
Address         DC          Rack        Status State   Load            Owns
xxx.xx.xxx.xx   datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  7.59 GB         51.39%
xxx.xx.xxx.xx   datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  394.24 MB       3.81%
xxx.xx.xxx.xx  datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  4.42 GB         44.80%

and my configuration in YAML is as below.

`hinted_handoff_enabled: true

max_hint_window_in_ms: 3600000 # one hour

hinted_handoff_throttle_delay_in_ms: 50

partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner

commitlog_sync: periodic

commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 120000

flush_largest_memtables_at: 0.75

reduce_cache_sizes_at: 0.85

reduce_cache_capacity_to: 0.6

concurrent_reads: 32

concurrent_writes: 24

sliced_buffer_size_in_kb: 64

rpc_keepalive: true

rpc_server_type: sync

thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15

thrift_max_message_length_in_mb: 16

incremental_backups: true

snapshot_before_compaction: false

column_index_size_in_kb: 64

in_memory_compaction_limit_in_mb: 64

multithreaded_compaction: false

compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16

compaction_preheat_key_cache: true

rpc_timeout_in_ms: 50000

index_interval: 128`

Is there something I may be missing? Are there any problems in the config?

Comment: There was a mistake on my version mentioned. The installed version is 1.0.5 and not .8. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally solved my problem in a different way. In fact I realized the problem is with my data model.

The problem comes because we we come from a RDBMS background. I restructured the data model a little and now, I get responses faster.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate your data in another column family where the key is your search data. Row slice are mutch faster

Personally I never got to use secondary index in production environments. Or I had problems with timeout, or the speed of data retrieve by secondary index was lower that the amount of data inserted. I think that it is related with not sequentially reading data and HD seek time.

Comment: I found another link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3545 through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741522/cassandra-performance-for-long-rows which might be related. Am checking to see if the latest version would provide a solution. If it was the problem with the cassandra version, then I probably have no other option but to migrate to newer version.

Answer (score 1):

If you come from a relational model, playOrm is just as fast and you can be relational on a noSQL store BUT you just need to partition your extremely large tables.  IF you do that, you can then use "scalable JQL" to do your stuff

@NoSqlQuery(name="findJoinOnNullPartition", query="PARTITIONS t(:partId) select t FROM TABLE as t INNER JOIN t.security as s where s.securityType = :type and t.numShares = :shares")

IT also has the @ManyToOne, @OneToMany, etc. etc. annotations for a basic ORM though some things work differently in noSQL but a lot is the similar.

Comment: Thanks will definitely take a look.